# React Context Vs Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I am a student trying to learn web development along with the ReactJs library. But I have a huge struggle selecting between **React Context and Redux** state management. I have never worked on real-time huge projects. So everyone is suggesting I should go with React context. Even my friend who is working on a real-time project in the IT field is using React Context instead of Redux in their project. So he suggests I should just stick with React Context. But I think Redux was there even before React context and is really suitable for huge projects. So a lot of the older projects may be using Redux. But Redux is really hard compared to React Context.

Can anyone give me a suggestion on whether I should just stick with React Context or I should learn Redux?

Comment: Questions for suggestions are not suitable here. However, I recently researched about the same thing. What I found was, React Context should not be used as a global state management tool. [This](https://dev.to/javmurillo/react-context-all-in-one-54ck) was helpful. Consider using `redux-toolkit` and redux. If your app doesn't need a _global state management_, then there is no need for Redux. So it is based on your project.

Comment: It is entirely up to you.  There is no clear cut way to tell you which to go with and trying to do so is opinionated.  You can do very large projects with just Context, I have done it.  I have also done small projects with Redux and it didn't exactly feel like overkill.  They both have pros and cons and should be familiar tools in your toolchest.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the scope of your project. There can be some problems with React Context with high frequency updates, but if it is mostly low frequency ( theme changes, authentication ) then just use React Context because it's simply better if you plan to use the data only in ReactJS and it's additional packages

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is a good idea to know both. I would start with React context which is much smaller and easier to grasp, and out of the box.

Then you can switch to redux - and do some work with it. You will learn both since both are not that difficult.